# Trigger on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I need some help. I´m new to SQL and everything I want is a trigger to update a column (`est`) when I use INSERT with `sex = 'F'` in the `Peop` table. Is it possible?
My DBMS is PostgreSQL.

I´ve tried this code but isn´t right. I´m getting this hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

```
CREATE FUNCTION tEst() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM Peop;
      IF Peop.est = 'A' AND Peop.sex = 'F' THEN
         UPDATE Peop SET est = 'B';
      END IF;
      RETURN NULL;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Peop
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tEst();

INSERT INTO Peop (name, sex) VALUES ('Mary', 'F');
```

By default, `est` column have `'A'` value.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple task, but you should to use a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` row trigger. There is possibility

- get information about data in related (inserted, updated, deleted) rows.
- modify data, that will be stored in table.

Your example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tEst() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.est = 'A' AND NEW.sex = 'F' THEN
    NEW.est = 'B';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tEst_trg BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON peop
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tEst();
```

You can see more examples in [related plpgsql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)